# Importing Test Database to Main Database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-migration

My problem is that I decided to have a Test Database where I put the data I'm testing and where I can play around without any issue. When everything seems ok I migrate the data to the "official" database, where I plan to migrate different Test DBs.

The problem are child tables. I have:

```
Table1:          Table2:          Child:
- id             -id              -idTable1
- name           -name            -idTable2
- url            -type            -quantity
```

To migrate Table1 and Table2 I thought to create a temporaryID on the "official" Database. When I want to migrate the table "Child" the only thing I can think of is to check every single row and update it with the corresponding new ids.
Isn't there a better way to do this?

I also thought to simply forget about Test DB and work only with the "official" one, but I am afraid of having to start again from scratch every time I make a mistake.

I think I've seen a couple of examples here on SO, but they seems much more complicated than what I need.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is that you don't want to avoid duplicate ids on the 2 (or more) databases,
you should read about "auto-increment-increment" and "auto-increment-offset".

if server 1 have:

```
auto-increment-increment                        = 4
auto-increment-offset                           = 1
```

then id number generated on that server is going to be: 1,5,9,13...

and the 2nd server configed like

```
auto-increment-increment                        = 4
auto-increment-offset                           = 2
```

the id numbers on the 2nd server is going to be 2,6,10,14..

that alow you to copy data, inlcuding the id number, between the servers

Comment: That would be nice if I have two Test Db, but I don't know how many I will have. :(

Comment: the exemple was for a up to 4 config, so set auto-increment-increment to 100, 1000 or higher :-)